# Sharing data on WhatsApp not working on android 11

Tags: android, image, android-intent

After upgrading my project on API 30, I checked WhatsApp data sharing via intent not working on android 11 device May b due to [**Package visibility in Android 11**](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility)

```
 val imgBitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(mContext.contentResolver, bitmap, "eVitalRx_Greetings_" + Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), null)
    val imgUri = Uri.parse(imgBitmapPath)
    val whatsappIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    if (appInstalledOrNot(mContext, "com.whatsapp")) {
        whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp")
    } else {
        whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b")
    }
    whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg)
    whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri)
    whatsappIntent.type = "image/jpeg"
    whatsappIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    try {
        mContext.startActivity(whatsappIntent)
    } catch (ex: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Whatsapp not installed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

It displaying the message `"Whatsapp not installed"` in android 11 device.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Check below answer brother

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, I got an answer by spending time with the original document and some other links.

if you want any kind of interaction with other apps you must add the package's name into the manifest file.

```
 <queries>
       
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
        <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
       
 </queries>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9


hope it can help u

Comment: Have you able to share images to whatsapp?

Comment: getting an error from whatsapp "The file format is not supported"

Comment: thats file issue not sharing issue

Comment: Working as on 21st march 2021

Comment: getting error: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
if I add this in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @abhilashkaveriappa hove you solved it or not??

Answer (score 2):

Add this in manifest file, I hope this helps you.Please Let me know if it works.....  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />`